# Display Comments while Running Script

Tags: postgresql, raiserror

I've seen the answer to this question in a couple posts. However when I the below which was an answer coming from another post, I get an error. My objective is to simply write comments to the screen as I execute DML commands in a script. However I have not found a simple way to do this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raise_exception(text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE EXCEPTION '%', $1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Called like this: select * from sp_send_msg('go for it');

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT send_comment('Writing widgets to temporary table');
SELECT * INTO t_widgets FROM widgets;

SELECT send_comment('Writing temporary table into new widget table');
INSERT INTO new_widgets
SELECT * FROM t_widgets;
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful guidance on this. I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.7.

Answer (score 2):

You should `raise notice` instead of `raise exception`. The former will show a message and the latter is treated as an error and will abort your transaction.

Comment: Is there a way to do this outside a function? I have a very long script, many tables creation and updates and I'd like to have a message like "Table X created" as my script is running (like you could do with a simple "print "Table X created" in python.

Comment: You could just use `select 'message text'` - it would be printed on screen.

Comment: That's it? Thanks!! Wouldn't have thought of that! :)